# Too few arguments to function error message

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller:

```
public function deleteRoom($id){
     $this->Room->deleteRoom($id);
     $this->index();
    }
```

view:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" value="<?php echo $data['room_id']; ?>" href="<?= site_url('AdminController/deleteRoom'); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

and it displayed like this: Message:

> Too few arguments to function AdminController::deleteRoom(), 0 passed
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\hrCI\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and
>   exactly 1 expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the id in the link.
Try

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" value="<?php echo $data['room_id']; ?>" href="<?= site_url('AdminController/deleteRoom/'.$data['room_id']); ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>
```

Comment: You may also have to update the routes config, I can't remember. If you get a 404, that's why.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="<?= site_url('AdminController/deleteRoom/' . $data['room_id']); ?>">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
```

check this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).